# Unhandled promise rejection even though I do handle it

Tags: javascript, promise, request

I wrapped a `request-promise-native` call in a function that returns a promise.

```
import request from 'request-promise-native';
function requestWrapper(url) {
    return request(url)
        .then(data => {...})
        .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
}
```

Simple right?

Now I'm using this function, and `then`works ok, but `catch` never catches the `Promise.reject`:

```
requestWrapper('http://some-url.com')
    .then(data => {...})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I never get to the call's `catch`!
If I change the return statement in the `catch` of `requestWrapper` to this:

```
.catch(err => err)
```

or even this:

```
.catch(err => Promise.resolve(err))
```

to return a `resolve`, I get the error stack on the `then` of the `requestWrapper` call just as expected.

And node shouts:

```
(node:24260) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): ...
```

Comment: did you tried error callback in then?

Comment: try `.then(data => {...}, err => console.log(err))`

Comment: @zabusa the `then` works fine. I need to catch errors, it does reach the `catch` statement in `requestWrapper`, then problem is how this is handled when I call the function.

Comment: Maybe don't catch it in the requestWrapper, only when you call the function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok thanks to @pathurs and @Hendry I got what I needed.

First of all, the right way is what @Hendry suggested which was to not handle the catch in the wrapper, rather in the function call. This is the way I went:

```
function requestWrapper(url) {
    return request(url)
        .then(data => {...})
}
requestWrapper('http://some-url.com')
    .then(data => {...})
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

Great!
But apparently, @pathurs way also works:

```
function requestWrapper(url) {
        return request(url)
            .then(data => {...})
            .catch(err => Promise.reject(err));
    }
    requestWrapper('http://some-url.com')
        .then(data => {...}, err => console.log(err));
```

I don't understand if that's a native feature, or some addition to `request` library:
https://github.com/request/request-promise#thenonfulfilled-onrejected

Answer (score 4):

if you are not getting that then do this workaround.

In order to handle rejections the following new events will be fired on `process`:

#### Event 'unhandledRejection':

Emitted whenever a possibly unhandled rejection is detected.
This event is emitted with the following arguments:

reason the rejection `reason` of the promise susprected in having an unhandled rejection
`p` the promise suspected in having an unhandled rejection itself.

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', function(reason, p){
    console.log("Possibly Unhandled Rejection at: Promise ", p, " reason: ", reason);
    // application specific logging here
});
```

For more info [Unhandled Rejection](https://gist.github.com/benjamingr/0237932cee84712951a2)

Comment: Amazing help @zabusa! This allowed me to pin point the cause of the issue, since for some reason Try/Catch blocks weren't catching the error I was having